# Is it possible to use variable values as one of the union types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to achieve something like this example in Typescript:

```
const appleOption:string = 'Apple';
const orangeOption:string = 'Orange';

export type FruitType = appleOption | orangeOption   //the compiler wouldn't allow this.

//my intention is for writing of the type be in variable and not their actual strings so that it's easier for me to refactor them in future
const eventType:FruitType = orangeOption;
```

Instead of typing out the union types as literal strings for `FruitType`, I'm hoping to use variables so that when I need to use the value again, I don't have to rewrite them out as magic strings, but as variables which I can refactor easily at a later time. I was trying to see if I could have an alternative to numeric enums in Typescript.

Is it possible to make use of a variable's value as one of the union type options?

Comment: It sounds like you want an `enum`.

Comment: @ssube yes, but a string enum, which is what I'm trying to emulate.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, the answer is no, you can't, at least not as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to use Enums, you can define an actual string as one of the union types:

```
type FruitType = 'orange' | 'apple' | 'banana'
let validFruit: FruitType = 'orange' // compiles fine
let invalidFruit: FruitType = 'tomato' // fails compilation
```

Or if you want to have a separate type for every string:

```
type OrangeType = 'orange'
type AppleType = 'apple'
type FruitType = OrangeType | AppleType
```

Comment: Like I've mentioned in my question, I'm hoping for a way to not write the literal strings many times so that if I ever refactor, say changing `apple` to `apples`, it would be easier if they were all variables.

Comment: How about putting the strings into separate types?

Comment: Ahh! +1! Why didn't I think of this! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: Oh wait! Actually, there is still a problem to this technique. When I declare an event type like so: `const eventType:FruitType = OrangeType;`, I get an error saying `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OrangeType'.`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? OrangeType is a type, you cannot assign it to a variable as value.

Comment: I was hoping to do that so that I won't have to write out the event name in strings but in some kind of variable that I can refactor easily.

Comment: I don't think you can swap between values and types. Sorry :(